# Put JSON data inside another object of the same JSON

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to put the images that are on "included" into "data:{relationships: { field_imagen: { data" but the problem is that i just managed to put only the first image into every index using map and find

```
 noticiasImages.forEach(function(data: {  relationships: { field_imagen: {data: {id:any}}}} ) {
      var nestedArray = noticiasData.map((noticiasImages: { id: any; }) => noticiasImages == noticiasData);
      data = nestedArray && noticiasImages || noticiasData;
    });
```

And this is my json (example node)

```
    {
   "data": [
         "relationships": {
            "field_imagen": {
               "data": [
                  {
                     "type": "file--file",
                     "id": "dba917f0-b80f-45ed-a569-69f2ba2b482d",
                  }
               ],
            }
         ]
      },
```

this is the included object, who is in the same level as data

```
"included": [
     "attributes": {
        "drupal_internal__fid": 8798,
        "langcode": "es",
        "filename": "_DSC6472 - copia.jpg",
        "uri": {
           "value": "public:\/\/2019-11\/_DSC6472 - copia.jpg",
           "url": "\/sites\/default\/files\/2019-11\/_DSC6472%20-%20copia.jpg"
        },
     },
  ,
```

Expected Result:

```
   "data": [
      "relationships": {
         "type": "node--actualidad_institucional",
         "id": "71514647-af49-4136-8a28-9563d133070a",
            "field_imagen": {
               "data": [
                  {
                     "type": "file--file",
                     "id": "dba917f0-b80f-45ed-a569-69f2ba2b482d",
                "uri": {
                   "value": "public:\/\/2019-11\/_DSC6472 - copia.jpg",
                   "url": "\/sites\/default\/files\/2019-11\/_DSC6472%20-%20copia.jpg"
                },
            }
         }
      },
```

I put the uri from included into field_imagen. Tried to resolve like that, but it just put only the first image of the Array from the included object in every node:

```
  showNoticias() {
    this.frontService.getNoticias()
      .subscribe((data: Noticias) => {
        this.noticiasImages = Array.from(data.included);
        this.noticiasData = Array.from(data.data);
        let noticiasImages = this.noticiasImages.map((data: {id: any}) => data.id);
        let noticiasData = this.noticiasData.map((data:{relationships: { field_imagen: { data: { id: any; }}}}) => data.relationships.field_imagen.data.id);


        noticiasImages.forEach(function(data: {  relationships: { field_imagen: {data: {id:any}}}} ) {
          var nestedArray = noticiasData.map((noticiasImages: { id: any; }) => noticiasImages == noticiasData);
          data = nestedArray && noticiasImages || noticiasData;
        });

      console.log(data);

      });
  }
```

Hope you can help me, thanks!

UPDATE: tried that but didnt work like expected

```
    let merged = data.data.map((data:{relationships: { field_imagen: { data: any }}}) => Object.assign({}, noticiasImages));
    console.log(data)
    console.log(merged)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes using regular `for` loops are a better option. Using `map` with objects that have that many properties can get confusing. And using `forEach` will not give you access to the `i` index of the iteration in the loop, which makes things easier in this case.

```
for (let i = 0; i < obj.included.length; i++) {
    let uri = obj.included[i].attributes.uri;
    obj.data[i].relationships.field_imagen.data[0] = {
      ...obj.data[i].relationships.field_imagen.data[0],
      ...uri
    }
  }
  console.log(obj)
```

Output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "relationships": {
                "field_imagen": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "type": "file--file",
                            "id": "dba917f0-b80f-45ed-a569-69f2ba2b482d",
                            "value": "public://2019-11/_DSC6472 - copia.jpg",
                            "url": "/sites/default/files/2019-11/_DSC6472%20-%20copia.jpg"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "included": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "drupal_internal__fid": 8798,
                "langcode": "es",
                "filename": "_DSC6472 - copia.jpg",
                "uri": {
                    "value": "public://2019-11/_DSC6472 - copia.jpg",
                    "url": "/sites/default/files/2019-11/_DSC6472%20-%20copia.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "And using forEach will not give you access to the i index of the iteration in the loop", nop, you can use `myArray.forEach((x:any,i:number)=>{console.log(x,i)})` idem with `map` or `find`